# popup a dynamic name file using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i am building a C# program to store update in notepad (.txt files) and sorting it using date so i used

> string up = string.Format("updates-{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now);

and now i am tring to make a display function to popup this file using

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", "update.txt");

the problem is that every day the update file will be renamed using the new date 
my question is :- is there any function,code or anything that allow me to popup a file which name is changing?
and um doing it using C# console application

Comment: If you are writing only several lines of text for each update you will be better of with writing all updates to a single file with every line begging with `[dd-MM-yyyy]`. Saves your hdd space + better track of the updates

Comment: actually no i am writing a whole enterprise update

Comment: What do you mean by 'popup a file' or do you just want to use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", up)?

Comment: i mean that when you type for example "show" and push return  a notepad opens

Answer (score 2):

I would say that @Hanks answer is absolutely correct, may be to just kind make it more precise, or addupted to your answer, you can try to do something like this, to get your 
"Current" file name:

```
string fileName = "updates-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt";
```

and after execute

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"complete path to your text file");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am sorry but a just a begginer

Comment: but how to make the file open after that??

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("updates-*.txt")
```

and then select one to show. But your date-format is not the easiest to sort for 'newest'.

Comment: i want to popup a file named "update-dd-MM-yyyy.txt" while dd-mm-yyyy is todays date

Comment: and this date changes everyday

Answer (score 0):

You've got everything you need for an answer in your question...

Combining this:

```
string up = string.Format("updates-{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now);
```

with this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", "update.txt");
```

should let you come up with this:

```
string up = string.Format("updates-{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", up);
```

Comment: zombiesheep thank you so much :D it was kind of silly of me not to try that :D thanks again :D